# Naming Convention for methods that return different types with similiar parameters

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have a `SearchService` which uses an algorithm for querying a database and returing the results.  There are a couple of different formats the data can be returned as, depending on what the invoker wants from the service.  These formats are:

- A list of entities that directly match against a table in the database
- A list of primary keys (Longs) of the records that match
- A list of 'search results' which is composed of a bunch of fields that are generally relevant to what a user would want to see from a search result (say a persons name, address phone number etc)

Currently my SearchService looks like:

```
public interface SearchService {
    public List<People> searchPeopleReturnEntity(SearchRequest request);
    public List<Long> searchPeopleReturnId(SearchRequest request);
    public List<SearchResult> searchPeopleReturnSearchResult(SearchRequest request);
}
```

I'm looking for advice on best practices regarding this.  Currently the naming convention seems pretty clunky and I believe there is a better solution than what I have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call them `findPeople()`, `findPeopleIDs()` and `findPeopleResults()`.

Comment: This is the one I went with as it contains the connotation of 'search' (as opposed to canonically returning a set of record that 'get' implies) in addition to implicitly telling the caller what it will be returning.

Answer (score 9):

I'd call them something simple like `getPeople`, `getIds`, `getSearchResults`.

If you need these same 3 methods for entities other than people, I'd consider making some generic intermediate type defining them, allowing you to write something like this:

```
List<People> people = service.getPeople(request).asEntities();
List<Long> fooIds = service.getFoos(request).asIds();

// or something like this
List<People> people = service.searchPeople().getEntities(request);
```

Comment: +1. I was going to suggest `findPeople`, `findIds`, and `findSearchResults`

Answer (score 0):

If your service can return other instances as well (besides People), I'd name them

- findPeopleEntities()
- findPeopleIds()
- getSearchResult() or getPeopleSearchResult()   (you generally don't *find* search results ;) )

If `SearchResult` is used for people only, I'd also name it `PeopleSearchResult`. Otherwise I'd give it a generic parameter like `SearchResult<T>` and then `List<SearchResult<People>> getPeopleSearchResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use the `searchBy...` approach? though I agree that denotes you will return same results. 
Perhaps you can refactor a bit:

- search... will return a List (I'm guessing ID's in the database?)
- then add a getPeople( List ) which actually returns the list of objects for those ID's

so your searc... methods always return ID's and then you have specialized functions to transform those into "proper" search results?

Comment: I originally started doing the searchBy.. approach but for the particular domain I'm working in that connotates the parameters that the results are matched against, not the return type.  for example `searchByName` would mean the results match the given name, rather than returning a list of Names

Answer (score 0):

In case it isn't obvious, there is no real "best practice" naming scheme for this kind of method.

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be:

```
public <T> T findPeople(SearchRequest request, Class<T> resultClass);
```

You can then return different things according to whether resultClass is Person.class, Long.class, or SearchResult.class.

Or, less horribly, you could do:

```
public <T> T findPeople(SearchRequest request, ResultConverter<T> resultConverter);
```

Where ResultConverter is an interface which takes some sort of raw search result and returns a suitable converted result. You could have canned instances for the common ones:

```
public class ResultConverters {
    public static final ResultConverter<Long> ID;
    public static final ResultConverter<Person> PERSON;
    public static final ResultConverter<SearchResult> SEARCH_RESULT;
}
```